# Greek New Testament data sets to download?

Tags: greek, john

I want to capture the text of John with only strong's numbers, or some other more complicated data format.

For example, I'd like to have John 1:1 at least as:

> 1722 746 1510 3588 3056 2532 3588 3056 1510 4314 3588 2316 2532 2316 1510 3588 3056

I'd like to be able to run algorithmic analysis on the word usage and do correlations.  I know this is a specific case, but is there a way to capture the text in a way I am sure that Biblehub and other sites have it under their hood.  Perhaps the text where each word has the conjugation details and the link to the strong's entry.  I'd essentially like a dataset that can create the current standard (NA28) greek new testament with links to the strong's concordance entries and the underlying parsed word-type.

**Is anyone aware of a location to download these kind of datasets for my own personal parsing and analysis?  Open source is best, but possibly for purchase is ok?**

Comment: Why not just use [Theophilos](http://theophilos.com/download.htm), along with its [three Greek New Testament modules](http://theophilos.com/lib01.asp) ?

Comment: @Lucian I don't know why not...hence the asked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the full answer that I believe gives everything that one would need to write automated parsing software or otherwise an application that worked with the biblical text programatically.

The following are github project links:

- [OpenHebrewBible](https://github.com/eliranwong/OpenHebrewBible) aligning BHS with WLC; bridging ETCBC, OpenScriptures & Berean data on Hebrew Bible.

  - This project has a single text file that contains the entire "[Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblia_Hebraica_Stuttgartensia)" (BHS) which is the standard academic critical edition of the Masoretic text with vowel pointings and cantillation marks.  This text is derived from the [Westminster Leningrad Codex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leningrad_Codex) dated to c.1008AD.  This single tab delimited text file has each of the words and prepositions (480k lines) and 20 columns of data consisting of 39 books of the Hebrew Bible.
  - Categories of data include KJV to BHS verse labels and alignment, clause layouts, raw hebrew, phonetic transcription in using english characters, strong's number, morphological codes, and english translations.  There are also formatting notes (paragraph and poetic text flags)
- [OpenGNT](https://github.com/eliranwong/OpenGNT/) Open Greek New Testament Project; NA28 / NA27 Equivalent Text & Resources

  - This project contains, amongst other things, a single text file with the entire greek new testament and associated academic parsings.  This is an attempt to match the standard critical edition of the greek text found in the NA28 [Novum Testamentum Graece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novum_Testamentum_Graece).
  - The text file contains 138k lines (one per word in the text).  There are 11 parsed columns (and other associated files with more parsings).  Highlights include clause id, flag to an old testament reference, book/chapter/verse labels, raw parsed greek (with and without accents), Morphological Analysis Codes, strong's numbers, a bunch of other lexicon entry IDs, transliterations, translations, punctuation marks, etc.
- [LXX-Rahlfs-1935](https://github.com/eliranwong/LXX-Rahlfs-1935) Septuagint database based on Rahlfs 1935 edition

  - This project is a little less coordinated, but contains all the mappings of a version of the LXX as well as strong's numbers, unaccented, and accented greek along with book partitions.
- [OpenScriptures](https://github.com/openscriptures) contains many other projects related to lexicons and some other sources for the text as well, but I have not dug into these in great detail.  They have a nice source for [Strongs hebrew and greek dictionaries](https://github.com/openscriptures/strongs). As well as the [Brown-Driver-Briggs (BDB) Hebrew Lexicon](https://github.com/openscriptures/HebrewLexicon).