# "Original" Koine Greek New Testament data download?

Tags: greek, new-testament

I saw [Greek New Testament data sets to download?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48386/greek-new-testament-data-sets-to-download) but wasn't sure that was the "[Koine greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koine_Greek)" ancient text, do we have a copy of that available on the web somewhere for free? I am not sure exactly what I am looking for, other than saying I am looking for "the closest to the original Ancient Greek text", not a modern Greek Bible. The Septuagint seems to be the Greek "Old Testament", so probably looking for some/all of the [New testament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Testament).

What copy is best for that as a text download, in as close to possible of the original Koine Greek? Do any of [these](https://github.com/topics/greek-new-testament) look promising? I can't quite tell and don't have enough knowledge.

Comment: See https://biblehub.com/nestle/john/1.htm  This extends to the OT as well.

Comment: See also https://www.sbl-site.org/assets/pdfs/bibletexts/UBS4/UBS4_GNT_SBL.pdf

Comment: The Stephens text of 1551 [the Textus Receptus](https://archive.org/details/englishmansgreek00step/page/n3/mode/2up) is provided here (The Englishman's Greek New Testament) with an interlinear translation.

Comment: See ebible org, for all public domain bibles, and www MyBible.zone app for phone. Also download Paratext.org for various free text including Greek. And theword.net app for PC

Comment: Eliran Wong OpenGNT is fine. That's what u need. Any critical open gnt. There maybe others as well.

Comment: When you say "original Koine Greek", are you prepared to accept transcriptions and critical texts with diacritics and lower case letters or do you want something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:P46.jpg ?

Comment: @Henry Exactly, I would like without diacritics and lower-case letters just like that image you posted, but I guess there is probably not that in existence :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want uncial script (capital letters) then go for [Statistical Restoration](https://github.com/Center-for-New-Testament-Restoration/SR) version. It is copyright-free and you can use the dataset of Eliran Wong or others for the Strongs' and morphological codes to make an app.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methodologies for reconstructing the text of the Greek New Testament, in addition to the SBL Greek New Testament. Each of these methodologies may have its own approaches and principles of textual criticism, which can lead to slight differences in the reconstructed text. Some of the most well-known methodologies include:

1. **Textus Receptus**: This is the form of the Greek New Testament text that served as the basis for the early English Bible translations, such as the King James Version. However, Textus Receptus is not widely used in academic circles today, as many consider more recent textual criticism methods to have produced more accurate results.
2. **Critical Texts** (Alexandrian): In addition to the SBL Greek New Testament, there are other widely recognized critical texts, such as the Novum Testamentum Graece (Nestle-Aland) and the United Bible Societies' Greek New Testament (UBS). These critical texts are based on a careful analysis of ancient manuscripts and apply principles of textual criticism to reconstruct the text of the New Testament.
3. **Majority Text**: This methodology favors the text found in the majority of known Greek manuscripts. Some argue that this may represent a more authentic textual tradition, while others disagree, asserting that older and well-preserved manuscripts are more reliable.
4. **Byzantine Text**: This is a textual tradition based on Greek manuscripts that were predominant in the Byzantine Empire. Some religious groups, such as the Greek Orthodox Church, favor this textual tradition.

However, it's important to note that the question of the "original text" of the New Testament is still a topic of debate among scholars and theologians. The academic consensus generally relies on the critical analysis of ancient manuscripts and linguistic evidence, but there will always be variations in the text among different editions. The quest for the original text is an ongoing challenge in biblical research. The aesthetics and grammar of the Greek text of the New Testament can also vary depending on the edition and the preferences of the editors, but the principles of textual criticism aim to determine the text closest to the original.

Combined Greek New Testament Manuscripts: 1550 Stephens Textus Receptus (τ), 1894 Scrivner Textus Receptus (σ), Byzantine Majority (β) and Alexandrian (α)

[GNTV- Greek NT with variants](https://www.obohu.cz/bible/index.php?k=Mt&kap=1&styl=GNTV)

"I understand that the quest for the "original" text of the New Testament is a complex challenge that involves various methodologies of reconstruction. From my perspective, I consider the "original" text to be an intersection of the various scientific methodologies used in Greek text reconstruction within academic research. By considering and comparing the conclusions reached by these different approaches, we can approximate a text that represents the consensus of the major findings. However, it's important to remember that the concept of "originality" in the context of the New Testament remains an ongoing topic of debate and research. I believe that this open approach to the diversity of methodologies can enrich our understanding of the New Testament text and its meaning."